# Linking forms to each other by buttons makes multiple windows of same form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to create two Windows Forms with buttons in order to linking them to each other, using this code:

```
private void cmdInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmInformation information = new frmInformation();
    information.Show();
}
```

(It's the same way for the second form)
When using this code you will have multiple windows of same form if you keep clicking the buttons. What can I do to stop this?

The best solution will be linking forms together without creating a new one, but I don't know any other way than one above.

**Tested Hide() but it just hides the multiple windows and program remain open even if you close last shown window.**

**Tried Close() but when it close the main form whole program is ended.**

Comment: What did you expect? `frmInformation information = new frmInformation();` will create a new `frmInformation` instance every time you click that button.

Comment: You need to disable the button once you have clicked it.  That way no more instances can be made.  Is this what you need?

Comment: @Transcendental  That's exactly my problem, too. I don't know any way to link forms without creating a new one. I there is any that will be my answer.

Comment: This solved my problem:
[how-to-switch-between-forms-without-creating-new-instance-of-forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369893/how-to-switch-between-forms-without-creating-new-instance-of-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the creation of the opposing form outside of the click event.

```
frmInformation information = new frmInformation();

private void cmdInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    information.Show();
}
```

This will re-display the same form over and over maintaining any data even when the user closes it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dialog.

information.ShowDialog();

You can also read up on dialog results and get responses from your form if that is needed.

Comment: changed `Show()` to `ShowDialog()` but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create a FormFactory that keeps track of the instances, this way if the form doesn't exist you can create a new instance and show it. If the form exists you can just show the current instance.