# I have memory leak in vb.net how can I fix this other than using garbage collector?

Tags: vb.net

this is the first form known as a login when I switched from login to registration then registration to log in the memory keep increasing it won't stop how can I resolve this?

```vb
Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
        Me.Hide()
        Dim registration As New Registration()
        registration.Show()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()

        Close()
    End Sub
```

the second form is known as registration

```vb
  Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles linkLabel1.LinkClicked
        Me.Hide()
        Dim login As New Login()
        login.Show()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        Close()
    End Sub
```

I'm using materialskin and a panel with image on each form and
garbage collector won't work
and the close() looks like it didnt work

[image]

Comment: In your case, the GC collection is called when both forms are still being shown, so GC can't really free any resources. But, does the memory usage *really* becomes a problem?

Comment: yes it really becomes a problem it keep increasing after switching many times it wont stop

Comment: What if instead of closing & creating forms, you just keep them hidden and display them when needed?

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: Keep a reference of them either in static variable or passing them around, so instead of calling new & close all the time you just show & hide the instance.

Comment: i don't have any idea how to do that can you give me any reference or something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369893/how-to-switch-between-forms-without-creating-new-instance-of-forms

Comment: How are the images being added to the panels? That could be the source of the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it here's the code on
login form

```vb
Imports MaterialSkin.Controls

Public Class Login
    Inherits MaterialForm
   Private _registration As Registration

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frm2_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs)
        _registration = Nothing 'If form is closed make sure reference is set to null
        _registration.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
        If _registration Is Nothing Then
            _registration = New Registration() 'Create form if not created
            AddHandler _registration.FormClosed, AddressOf frm2_FormClosed 'Add eventhandler to cleanup after form closes
        End If

        _registration.Show(Me) 'Show Form assigning this form as the forms owner
        Hide()
    End Sub
```

registration form

```vb
Imports MaterialSkin.Controls

Public Class Registration
    Inherits MaterialForm
 Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles linkLabel1.LinkClicked
        Owner.Show()
        Hide()
    End Sub
```